# VS Code, open in default browser not working?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm having problems launching an html file into the chrome browser, usually I do this in VS Code by tapping Cmd+1 key, or by clicking the "go live" button, or also right-click on the html.index file then click "open in default browser".

I've rechecked my settings in VS Code, my default browser is set to Chrome. Have relaunched VS Code and even restarted my computer but still can't figure out what the issue is since no error messages are being displayed.

Then I tried downloading a plug-in "open in browser" and it also doesn't launch to chrome, however if I select to launch it with Firefox it works.

Not sure if this helps, but I just upgraded my macOS to Big Sur a couple days ago.

Has anyone encountered the same issue?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what's your os default browser? Please recheck if it is set to chrome.

Comment: Hi @dhruwlalan , yes I have rechecked again on my system preferences for Default browser, and it is set to Google Chrome.

Comment: If you are using `open in browser` plugin then you can manually set it's default browser setting to chrome, so in your  settings.json add this: `"open-in-browser.default": "chrome"` & if it still dosen't work then i think there might be some bug with chrome itself. Maybe you can reinstall chrome & see if that works?

Comment: Hi @dhruwlalan, I tried your suggestion in modifying the settings.json file it didnt work. However, reinstalling Google Chrome worked. Thank you!

Comment: Ohh nice to know that.:)